# Making PDF viewable but not downloadable on customer community

Tags: community, pdf, customer-community

I'm looking for recommendations for the best way to make PDF documents viewable on customer community but not downloadable. I know that Salesforce Content can be restricted that way but I wasn't sure if it could be applied to community. I also thought about PDF's attached to Knowledge articles in the community, but I wasn't sure if you could dis-allow downloading with Knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

From a practical standpoint, a PDF has to be downloaded into the browser for it to be opened by the Acrobat Reader plug-in. Once it's there, someone can always do a "Save As" in order to save the document locally.

Unless you render the PDF page by page as VisualForce content as opposed to PDF content, that would seem to be the only way you could prevent a user from downloading the document as a PDF. Otherwise, its all going to be handled by browser plug-ins.

I think you're going to need to do something server side to work around this issue. I've not done this before, but I'm guessing you'd need to create a controller to process each page as a blob. Someone else may have a more specific suggestion on the details of how to do what you're asking. I hope this at least helps provide some guidance or general direction for you.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to try and stay away from VF if possible but that may not be an option. We could do Content delivery, but they really want to it to be available as a tab in the community.

Comment: Any time a user hits a PDF link, unless you set up some kind of intervention to prevent it, its automatically going to download into the entire doc into browser as opposed to allowing you to control the process such that the doc is served page by page, The latter will require some kind of controller to make that happen. Obviously, you don't want to duplicate the Acrobat interface, and instead will want to convert it on the fly to HTML or XHTML if possible, esp when you have large documents with links to other pages that you won't want to lose. Either that or convert them in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of winter 15, there is [now programmatic access to the Content Deliveries API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HMq4AAG).  This allows you to deliver content to users without granting access to the library.

The PDF's are embedded in a SWF player and can be configured to include/exclude a download button.  If the download button is excluded, then it will be difficult for the average users to actually get the content on their computer, short of screen shooting each page.

**Example code using the Content Distribution object**

```
ContentDistribution cd = new ContentDistribution();
cd.name = 'test';
cd.ContentVersionId = '12312132abad';
cd.PreferencesAllowOriginalDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowPDFDownload = false;
cd.PreferencesAllowViewInBrowser = true;
insert cd;

cd = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE ID = :cd.Id];
System.debug(cd.DistributionPublicUrl);
```

Then just expose the `DistributionPublicUrl` to the Communities User.  You can also set things like expiration date or require a password to view it.